# How to update values of a column based on other table in Oracle SQL syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an `emp` table with these columns

```
emp_id  f_name      l_name      salary      dept_id
----------------------------------------------------
100     Steven      King        24000       90  
101     Neena       Kochhar     17000       50
102     Lex         De Haan     17000       90
103     Alexander   Hunold      9000        60
```

now I have `t_emp` table with these columns:

```
f_name      l_name      salary      dept_id
-------------------------------------------
Steven      King        24000       null 
Neena       Kochhar     17000       null
Lex         De Haan     17000       null
Alexander   Hunold      9000        null
```

Assume `dept_id` column was recently added here.

I want to update `t_emp.dept_id` column to be the same as `emp.dept_id` column.
How could I do that?

When I try below `insert into` query, I get error msg :

> Cannot insert NULL into ("GAURAV"."T_EMP"."LAST_NAME")

```
insert into t_emp(dept_id)
    select dept_id 
    from emp;
```

How could I do this single column update in `t_emp` table based on `emp` table?

Comment: `INSERT` creates new rows.  If you want to update existing rows, use `UPDATE` (or possibly `MERGE`)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first and last names provide the match between the tables, then you can use a correlated subquery like this:

```
update t_emp te
    set dept_id = (select e.dept_id
                   from emp e
                   where e.f_name = te.f_name and e.l_name = te.l_name
                  );
```

You can add `salary` equivalence in as well, if that is important.

Note that actually storing the column is not important.  You could fetch the information using a `join`:

```
select . . ., e.dept_id
from t_emp te join
     emp e
     on e.f_name = te.f_name and e.l_name = te.l_name;
```

It is usually better to save such information in one place and use `join`s to get the right info.